# What is more effective, a do while or a while?

Tags: efficiency, loops

I mean, with the same code, if I modify a do while into a while in this way:

do {$S;$} while ($B$) into a $S;$ while ($B$){$S;$} , there is any change 
in the code?

B = condition

S; = instructions

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*While* and *do while* differ only in the first execution when condition is false. If you ignore this difference it boils down to the place of condition check, in *while* the condition is checked and if it is true the statements are executed. In the *do while* the condition check is executed after the block execution.

The code is exactly the same, with one line reordered.

If you want to do micro-optimisations please check whether these are worthy of your time. Compiler does really great job nowadays, unless it doesn't then change the compiler.

So under the hood they are equivalent.

Comment: I would add that the while version of the code has code duplication, which is often a place where bugs creep in, if you need to change the code, you change one version and not the other.

Comment: @AntonioM.Burgueño In *while* you wrote *S* two times. Let's say you want to change *S* to *S1* in *do..while* you have to change only one block, in *while* you have to change both blocks. If you forget one, you have a bug.